# Are Java Servlets equivalent to Web Services

Tags: java, php, .net, web-services, servlets

I am familiar with Creating and consuming Web Services using .NET/PHP, but not familiar with Java Servlets.

Are they just equivalent to creating Web Services using .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No definitely not, standard definition: a servlet is a *Java programming language class* used to extend the capabilities of servers that host applications accessed via a request-response programming model. Servlets are **not tied to** a specific client-server protocol but they are most commonly used with HTTP and the word "Servlet" is often used in the meaning of "HTTP Servlet". Whereas a web service is programmable application logic accessible via standard Web protocols such as **SOAP** using **XML**.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not.

The *closest equivalent* to Servlets in the .Net framework is the [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx). However, I consider servlets to be far more easier to work with, than HttpHandlers.

Most of the HTTP-based processing of requests is performed eventually by servlets, in a JavaEE container. This is true even of *most* web-services in Java, where one can write a web-service in a particular framework, but eventually a servlet is *usually* responsible for performing the heavy-lifting. The same holds good for Java Server Pages (JSPs, which are compiled to servlets), and JSF (where a controller servlet - FacesServlet is responsible for processing of requests).

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not.

Java servlets can be used to implement web services, but the two concepts apply to different levels of abstraction:

A servlet is generally any Java class that runs on a web server and implements the [Java Servlet Specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-139443.html).  This includes methods to receive, process and respond to HTTP requests, among others.

A [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) is a specific way to establish machine-to-machine communication within a network, and can be implemented using a variety of protocols, technologies, and even paradigms.

Answer (score 1):

No, Servlets, which conforms to the Java Servlet API, is a protocol used for responding to requests (server requests). As mentioned by Jon Skeet (see comment, and thanks for the clear-up), servlets are protocol-neutral (They are not tied to a specific client-server protocol). `HttpServlet` is a Servlet that responds to HTTP requests. In Java, SOAP Web Services engines are written with a Servlet as a container to handle HTTP Web Services requests (with the exception of RMI Invocating Web Services).

Resources:

- [Wikipedia: Java Servlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet).
- [Java Servlet Specification API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-139443.html).

Comment: Servlets don't *have* to be used to service HTTP requests. They almost always are, but servlets themselves are somewhat protocol-neutral. HttpServlet is specialized for HTTP.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, you're absolutely correct. Thanks for seeing my mistake. Early morning SO! :)

Comment: @Gunner, they are not related at all. .NET WebServices conforms to the SOAP Protocol while Servlets service requests coming from client to server and provide a response. It's up to the developer to define how to service those request/response.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same.

A web service uses SOAP protocol and returns you XML, a servlet returns you HTML which you view in the browser

Answer (score 0):

No, It is the only way to implement Web Service which have two protocol,not only use SOAP,which too heavy,you can use lightweight protocol RESTFul.

Using NetBean develop very quickly.

Comment: That doesn't help. The OP refers Servlets (in Java) to .NET Web Service.